# what is the best approach for designing a php mysql user login system with three different access level?

Tags: php, mysql, login-control

I am a beginner with php and mysql. I am going to develop a web application which has three types of users, namely admins, staff and customers. Each have restricted access to differe parts of the application. Should I create a table for each group of users or just one table with a column specifying user type? Which approach is better? Is there other options? And at last, I really prefer to have one single login page for all three types of users.

Comment: the search term you are looking for is 'php role based security'

Comment: Thank you all and specially @pala for your great help.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I would prefer different tables and use also different login fields on your login page (or check every login in every table until you find the right one). This is easier if you have to connect tables and I.e. admins can do things, that causes links between different tables than those staff members could cause.
On the other hand the login process would be a little bit easier if it's in one table.

I've done a project, that sounds very similar to yours. Maybe it could help you sometimes if you have a look at it. You can find it at [GitHub](https://github.com/DevWurm/order_system).

Good luck with your project :)